# Can you continue to add products whilst in production mode

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I currently have Magento 2.1 running on a dedicated server. I have never change the "mode" since installation so I believe I'm still in default mode right now. So far i have installed a theme successfully and have added just over 650 products and am still going strong :-). I have multiple suppliers for the products I sell, so what I would like to do is add all products from my main supplier and go "live" by disabling maintenance mode and changing my Magento installation to "production mode". Not sure if this is the correct approach?

After switching to production mode and going live I'll still have a lot of products to add from my other suppliers. So my questions are:

1. **Is it fine to continue adding new products whilst in production mode** or should all products be added now in default/developer mode?
2. **What exactly do people mean when they say that your still "developing your store"** do they mean installing a theme, adjusting file system permissions, customizing front end with CSS and adding products/categories? or do they mean coding actual php modules? (which is what I assume "developer mode" is for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can totally add new products while in production mode.

Development refers mostly to coding understand theme, modules and 3rd party integration.

So yeah don't worry you can keep adding categories and products once you're shop is in production

Comment: Hey Raphael, thanks for the prompt response and for clearing that up for me! now i can continue as scheduled. much appreciated.

Comment: Can we do all development work in Production mode? sound silly but curious to know that PLEASE .

Comment: @Jai yes you totally can but you're gonna be way less efficient than in developer mode because you'll have to regenerate the static files manually everytime you make changes

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you couldn't! Such a weird mode it would've been. :-D But, of course you can. If you do development on "Production" mode, however, then you'll need to constantly delete cache and static content and redeploy it for any code change you make.